# Magento 2.1 how to trigger UI Component onUpdate() on load

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2

Trying to implement field dependency in magento 2.1. It works fine when change the value of field manually but it doesnt work on page loading using the value of field. Following is the code i used

listing_edit_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="property_features_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Property Features</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="is_propertyview_allowed">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Property View Allowed</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">DLBA_Properties/js/form/element/propertyviewalloweddate</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">is_propertyview_allowed</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_propertyview_allowed</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <!-- <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <!-- <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">12</item> -->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="view_allowed_till">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Viewing Allowed Till</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">view_allowed_till</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">view_allowed_till</item>
                    <item name="outputDateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd-MM-y</item>
                    <item name="inputDateFormat" xsi:type="string">y-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="area">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Area</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">area</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">area</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="bedrooms">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">No of Bedrooms</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">bedrooms</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">bedrooms</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="bathrooms">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">No of Bathrooms</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">bathrooms</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">bathrooms</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
```

propertyviewalloweddate.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox-toggle-notice',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($,_, uiRegistry, checkbox, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return checkbox.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            console.log(uiRegistry.get('index = is_propertyview_allowed').value());
            return this;
        },
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            this.checkIfAllowed(value);
            return this._super();
        },
        checkIfAllowed:function(value){
            console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);
            console.log(uiRegistry.get('index = is_propertyview_allowed').value());
            var allowed_date_field = uiRegistry.get('index = view_allowed_till');
            if (allowed_date_field.visibleValue == value) {
                allowed_date_field.show();
            } else {
                allowed_date_field.hide();
            }
            return this;
        }
    });

});
```

Following is the error. When i try to call uiRegistry in initialize function it throws following error

Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

It is the line console.log(uiRegistry.get('index = is_propertyview_allowed').value()); inside initialize function.

But it works fine inside onUpdate function. Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance